# Python CLI Menu

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I am trying to develop a menu which will:

1. Check to see if /tmp has write permissions from the user who is running the script.
2. Prompt the question : Are ALL your LOCAL repositories in the same location? e.g. /home/joe/hg/(y/n)
   If YES, then, prompt for the complete PATH's, of the repos:

   1. store the repo names (along with theor complete PATH) in a list
   2. copy some config files, from the directory /tmp/hg-jira-hook-config/ to ALL "home/joe/hg//.hg/"
   3. chmod 755 for all the config files for each repo.
3. If the answer to the question in Step 2 is "n" or "NO" or "no"
   then:

   1. ask for individual PATHs of the repos
   2. copy the config files
   3. chmod 755

I have a partially working script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys,os
import stat
import tempfile
import shutil

__title_prefix = 'Python %i.%i.%i %s %s' % (sys.version_info[0:4] +
                                           (sys.version_info[4] or "",))

if os.path.exists('/tmp'):
    pass
else:
    print '/tmp does not exist'
    sys.exit()

def isgroupreadable(filepath):
    st = os.stat(filepath)
    return bool(st.st_mode & stat.S_IRGRP)

src = '/tmp/hg-jira-hook-config/' # This directory will be created as a result of apt-get install <package>
                                  # and all config files will be copied 

if isgroupreadable('/tmp'):
    prompt_1 = ("Are ALL your LOCAL repositories in the same location? e.g. /home/joe/hg/<repo>[y/n], Press [q] when done\n")
    answer_1 = raw_input(prompt_1)
    if answer_1 == 'y' or None or 'YES' or 'yes':
        while True:
            answer_2 = raw_input("\n\nEnter the complete PATH of repos.Press [q] when done\n")
    elif answer_1 == 'n' or 'NO' or 'No' or 'no':
        result = raw_input("\n\nEnter the complete PATH of mercurial repositories you want this hook to be applied.Press [q] when done\n")
        print result

else:
    print 'cannot copy, wrong permissions on /tmp'


def main():

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

test run:

```
python preinst 
Are ALL your LOCAL repositories in the same location? e.g. /home/joe/hg/<repo>[y/n], Press [q] when done
y


Enter the complete PATH of repos.Press [q] when done
/home/joe/hg/app1


Enter the complete PATH of repos.Press [q] when done
/home/joe/hg/app2


Enter the complete PATH of repos.Press [q] when done
q


Enter the complete PATH of repos.Press [q] when done
```

so the question is:

How can i store PATH's in a LIST (or any other data structure)
and How do Exit the user from this loop

Comment: "How can i store PATH's in a LIST"?  Are you asking about `list` and `list.append`?  If so, please read a tutorial because list and append are usually covered.  Exit from a loop?  Are you asking about `break`?  If so, please read a tutorial, because `break` is usually covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all cases, the user must supply at least one path to the program. It is much much easier to supply that path or paths on the command line (using, say, `argparse`), than it is to make a nice interactive interface. Moreover, if you use an argument parser like `argparse` then your program will be automatically scriptable. In contrast, an interactive program is always as slow as its user. Therefore, I almost always prefer scriptable programs over interactive programs.

Here is how you could do this using [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse):

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('locations', nargs = '+')
    args=parser.parse_args()
    print(args.locations)
```

Running

```
% test.py /path/to/repo
['/path/to/repo']

% test.py /home/joe/hg /home/joe/test
['/home/joe/hg', '/home/joe/test']
```

---

`argparse` can also be used in conjunction with an interactive program. For example,

```
import argparse
import shlex
response = raw_input('Enter repo PATHs (e.g. /path/to/repo1 /path/to/repo2)')
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('locations', nargs = '+')
args=parser.parse_args(shlex.split(response))
print(args.locations)
```

---

`argparse` is part of the standard library as of Python 2.7. For Python 2.3 or better, you can [install argparse](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse).

Comment: in my case THIS is not possible, since this menu is run as a by product , so a human cannot run this by hand and supply arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you situation, but perhaps you could write a wrapper script around the top-level command the human is running, which accepts argparse style arguments. Then you could pass that information down to the script you are running "as a by product".

Comment: Sorry, i should explain better... This script is run as a pre-install script with "apt-get install <package name>" and is packaged with the debian package and hosted locally, so the only way to interact with the human is to prompt them , and on thta prompt, maybe i can have them write ALL the "PATHs" in one line and then store them in a list, right?

Comment: In that case, you could pass the response string from `raw_input` into `parser.parse_args`. I've added code above to show what I mean.